# Pyflakes returning erroneous syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

I'm writing a program that generates a random playing card and draws it in the `.stdout` terminal.
It keeps giving me `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` when I triple checked my code and everything is correct.

Input:

```
def drawCard():
    #cs and cr are global variables I declared in another function, so please disregard those.
    #also, Italic(), Bold(), etc are custom escape methods I made to format my text.
    #The indexing on cr and cs is to print the first character in the string (they are strings).
    cardlayout = f" ______\n|{cr[0]}|    |\n|{Bold(Underline(cs[0]))}{End()}|    |\n|  {Italic('0' + cr)}{End()} _|\n|    |{Bold(cs[0])}{End()}|\n|____{Underline('|' + cr[0])}{End()}|"
    if cr == '10':
        cardlayout = f" ______\n|{cr}|   |\n|{Bold(Underline(cs[0]))}{End()}|    |\n|  {Italic(cr)}{End()} _|\n|    |{Bold(cs[0])}{End()}|\n|{Underline('   |' + cr)}{End()}|"
    if cr == 'Ace' or cr == 'Jack' or cr == 'Queen' or cr == 'King':
         cardlayout = f" ______\n|{cr[0]}|    |\n|{Bold(Underline(cs[0]))}{End()}|    |\n| {Italic("a ")}{End()}_|\n|    |{Bold(cs[0])}{End()}|\n|____{Underline('|J')}{End()}|"
    print(cardlayout)
```

Output:

```
File "main.py", line 24
    cardlayout = f" ______\n|{cr[0]}|    |\n|{Bold(Underline(cs[0]))}{End()}|    |\n| {Italic("a ")}{End()}_|\n|    |{Bold(cs[0])}{End()}|\n|____{Underline('|J')}{End()}|"
                                                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How is my syntax invalid here?

Comment: The entire string is double-quoted, and by putting another double-quoted string inside the formatted portion, you're accidentally ending the string early (and `f"..."a` is a syntax error). If you replace the double-quotes in question with single-quotes it should be fine.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy I want the string inside of Italic() to have single quotes in it, that's the problem. If I try to use triple quotes I get another error. It won't take escape characters either.